# MS Access: Export multiple queries into separate Excel files

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel, ms-access-2016

I need to export a number of queries from Access into Excel.  (11 Tables to 11 Unformatted Excel Files)

The DB that I'm using has a front-end "User" Database, with a back end database with the bulk of the data.

I'm able to use the following code successfully:

```vb
Private Sub Command6_Click()
'Create Genie Files for Temp Deskop DB and Export Files to Excel

UID = Environ("Username")
excelsavepath = "C:\Documents and Settings\" & UID & "\Desktop\Monthly Audits - Desktop\"
    
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "CIDCASTDATA", excelsavepath & "CIDCASTDATA.xlsx, True"

MsgBox "All CIDCASTDATA havs been exported to the Monthy Audits-Desktop."
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

However, when I try to put multiple together, I get an error:

> Run-time error 3027: Cannot update. Database or object is read only.

```vb
Private Sub Command7_Click()
'Create Genie Files for Temp Desktop DB and Export Files to Excel

UID = Environ("Username")
excelsavepath = "C:\Documents and Settings\" & UID & "\Desktop\Monthly Audits - Desktop\"
    
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "CIDCASTDATA", excelsavepath & "CIDCASTDATA.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "CIDORGUNITS", excelsavepath & "CIDORGUNITS.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Cost Center List", excelsavepath & "Cost Center List.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "EmployeeChief", excelsavepath & "EmployeeChief.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Job Catalog-DLP", excelsavepath & "Job Catalog-DLP.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Org Unit Pull from SAP", excelsavepath & "Org Unit Pull from SAP.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "PA List", excelsavepath & "PA List.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR", excelsavepath & "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR_1", excelsavepath & "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR_1.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR_2", excelsavepath & "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR_2.xlsx, True"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR_3", excelsavepath & "SAP Position Pull-ALL WDPR_3.xlsx, True"

MsgBox "All Genie Files have been exported to the Monthy Audits ."
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

This error happens regardless of whether I create the Query in the Front End Database or the Back End Database.  However, when I manually export to Excel file-by-file, there are no issues from either DB.

Conversely, I have tried using the Macro Builder in Access, but can't figure out how/if I can use that to export Unformatted Excel files.

Comment: It looks like you've got a typo for your last parameters. For the first one as an example, your last parameter is `"CIDCASTDATA.xlsx, True"` but I bet you meant to write `"CIDCASTDATA.xlsx", True`